# Recurring event every x hours in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar

I need to create an hour-long event in Google Calendar that repeats every 124 hours, but there is only an option to repeat days.

I did some research, and it might be possible with some spreadsheet formulas, but I am not entirely sure how to do this.

Comment: Welcome. Just to clarify: you want the event to repeat every 5 days and 4 hours (124 hours)? Do you want this to repeat indefinitely? How are you proposing to create the event in the first instance? I can imagine a script that could count forward 124 hours and then create a new event, etc, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Sheets you can create a `.csv` file with all your custom settings and import it in your existing calendar.

Please read more about it in the official help page: [Advanced: Create or edit .csv or iCal files before you import](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118)

**NOTE**: As mentioned *"**Repeating events** might not show up that way if you import them from a .csv file, but they'll be on your calendar as a **series of one-time events**."*

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept.